# Combining plots and overlapping geom_rect objects using ggplot2 and cowplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cowplot

I am going to sum up some questions made before in this forum ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603444/representing-in-one-chart-two-plots-in-different-axes-using-ggplot/50608934#50608934), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606795/confidence-interval-square-in-a-plot-with-one-variable-in-each-axis-in-ggplot?noredirect=1#comment88225564_50606795)), but in this case with my real datasets and codes, all together. I am stuck and need help to know to code it properly.

Let's start with the datasets. Download and load them from here:

```
perio <- read.csv(url("http://vivaelsoftwarelibre.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/perio.csv"), header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".")
pk    <- read.csv(url("http://vivaelsoftwarelibre.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/pk.csv"),    header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".")
```

As you see, we have two different datasets.

Now, I am going to calculate confidence limits (CL) of groups A and B in `pk` and A and B in `perio`, having been previously calculated means, sd, and legnth per group.

```
# Calculate mean, sd and length in pk by Comparison
mean_pk   <- aggregate(pk[, 1], list(Type=pk$Comparison), mean)
sd_pk     <- aggregate(pk[, 1], list(Type=pk$Comparison), sd)
length_pk <- aggregate(pk[, 1], list(Type=pk$Comparison), length)

# 95 confidence limits of pk by Comparison (A and B)
CL_A_pk <- qnorm(0.975)*sd_pk[1,2]/sqrt(length_pk[1,2])
CL_A_pk_lw <- mean_pk[1,2] - CL_A_pk
CL_A_pk_up <- mean_pk[1,2] + CL_A_pk

CL_B_pk <- qnorm(0.975)*sd_pk[2,2]/sqrt(length_pk[2,2])
CL_B_pk_lw <- mean_pk[2,2] - CL_B_pk
CL_B_pk_up <- mean_pk[2,2] + CL_B_pk

# Calculate mean, sd and length in perio by Site
mean_perio <- aggregate(perio[, 2], list(Type=perio$Site), mean)
sd_perio <- aggregate(perio[, 2], list(Type=perio$Site), sd)
length_perio <- aggregate(perio[, 2], list(Type=perio$Site), length)

# 95 confidence limits of pk by Site (A and B)
CL_A_perio <- qnorm(0.975)*sd_perio[1,2]/sqrt(length_perio[1,2])
CL_A_perio_lw <- mean_perio[1,2] - CL_A_perio
CL_A_perio_up <- mean_perio[1,2] + CL_A_perio

CL_B_perio <- qnorm(0.975)*sd_perio[2,2]/sqrt(length_perio[2,2])
CL_B_perio_lw <- mean_perio[2,2] - CL_B_perio
CL_B_perio_up <- mean_perio[2,2] + CL_B_perio
```

Now, I am ggplotting them separately, with histograms, densities and geom_rects objects, taking into account the groups (A, B)

```
# ggplot histogram of pk
library(ggplot2)
dif_pk <- ggplot(pk, aes(x=Count, color=Comparison, fill=Comparison)) + 
  geom_density(alpha=0.25) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha=0.25) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=CL_A_pk_lw, xmax=CL_A_pk_up, ymin=0, ymax=0.3), alpha = 0.5, colour = "darkred", fill = "red") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=CL_B_pk_lw, xmax=CL_B_pk_up, ymin=0, ymax=0.3), colour = "darkblue", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0), lwd=0.5, lty=2) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  lims(x=c(-50, 50), y=c(0,0.3))

# ggplot histogram of perio
library(ggplot2)
dif_perio <- ggplot(perio, aes(x=vsSAP, color=Site, fill=Site)) + 
  geom_density(alpha=0.25, kernel = "gaussian", adjust = 2) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha=0.25) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=CL_A_perio_lw, xmax=CL_A_perio_up, ymin=0, ymax=2, alpha=0.5), colour = "darkblue", fill = "blue", alpha =0.5) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=CL_B_perio_lw, xmax=CL_B_perio_up, ymin=0, ymax=2, alpha=0.5), colour = "darkred", fill = "red", alpha =0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0), lwd=0.5, lty=2) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top", limits = c(-75, 20)) +
  scale_y_reverse(position = "right",limits = c(2,0)) +
  coord_flip()
```

These are the results:
[image]
[image]

Now, I am merging both of them using `cowplot`

```
library(cowplot)
ggdraw(dif_pk) +
  draw_plot(dif_perio)
```

With this result:
[image]

## What do I want?

Bearing in mind the last picture, I need to correct several issues in order to obtain the perfect plot:

- **Perfect alignment of the axis of both plots using `cowplot`**. You can see in the top left and bottom right corners how the axis are misaligned. So I would like they form a complete and uniform rectangle.
- I want to represent the 95 confidence limits but only showing the overlapping areas of both plots. So **only two overlapping rectangles might appear approximately in the center of the chart**, one for the A group and one for the B group. The vertical and horizontal bars must disappear.
- I would like previous rectangles to be `alpha = .5`, so that the overlapping area between both is evident.
- Each of the previous rectangles must keep the color from each group: A (red) and B (blue).
- I would like to remove one legend and replace the other in order to ease interpretation.

The rectangles should be something similar to these that have been done manually using Inkscape:

[image]

I would sincerely appreciate your help. Hope an R coding expert help me!

Comment: I'm not totally clear how you want the rectangles to look in the end, but you can get things aligned using the `align_plots` function from **cowplot**.  The example in the documentation is pretty useful.  Your rectangles are being drawn many times, so, e.g., add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to those layers to get transparency.  See [this vignette](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/inst/doc/shared_legends.html) for info on shared legends.

Comment: Hi @aosmith, thanks for your comment. I edited the question adding at the end a manually-edited plot using Inkscape of the expected plot using R coding. Hope you can help me... I'll appreciate much your help!

Comment: You need to align the plots as shown in the example code here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cowplot/versions/0.9.2/topics/align_plots